# Unable to Instantiate X509Certificate2 from Byte Array

Tags: c#, .net, cryptography, asp.net-web-api2, x509certificate2

I am trying to use a self-signed certificate to configure IdentityServer3,
I used openssl to create a x509 certificate as follows:
openssl req -x509 -sha256 -days 365 -key key.pem -in csr.csr -out certificate.pem
then merged the key and cert using :
pkcs12 -export -in my-cert.pem inkey my-key.pem -out xyz-cert.pfx
i then converted the content of xyz-cert.pfx to Base64String which is stored in a key in web.config, then tried to use the certificate to instantiate X509Certificate2 as follows:

```
var certificate = Convert.FromBase64String(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SigningCertificate"]);

        var options = new IdentityServerOptions
        {
            SigningCertificate = new X509Certificate2(certificate, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SigningCertificatePassword"]),
            RequireSsl = false, // DO NOT DO THIS IN 
            Factory = factory
        };
```

the following exception is then thrown:
[image]

I can't figure out where i got it wrong.
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var options = new IdentityServerOptions
{
    string CertText = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SigningCertificatePassword"];
    byte[] certBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(certText);
    SigningCertificate = new X509Certificate2(certificate, certBytes),
    RequireSsl = false, // DO NOT DO THIS IN 
    Factory = factory
};
```

Comment: Thanks, this didn't work, after trying this and it didn't work, i went and created a new key, tested, and its working. Don't know what i got wrong while creating the initial key

Comment: So did it finally work with this or with your original code?